# How to link to specific words in HTML

Tags: html

I'm creating a simple static website, and I wish to link from one page to a specific word or phrase on another. Using an anchor only appears to cause Chrome to link to a specific line, even when that word is the only content anchored on that line. Any further suggestions?

Edit: Specifically, I wish for the target word or phrase to be clearly disambiguated from all other content on the page, even on the same line.

Comment: What would you expect to happen? How would you want to jump to the image without jumping to the line?

Comment: @Truth: There's no images involved here. Also, I wish for that specific word to be clearly disambiguated from the other content on the line.

Comment: How about something like this: http://www.catchmyfame.com/2009/08/01/the-css3-target-pseudo-class-selector/

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. Post as an answer and I will accept.

Comment: I meant word, got confused there.

Comment: Hmm. Is it possible to use that technique to target more than one span with the same id?

Comment: Ahem. I mean, just, more than one element- obviously they'd have to have different ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using the CSS target pseudo selector (element:target) as shown at http://www.catchmyfame.com/2009/08/01/the-css3-target-pseudo-class-selector/.